# Moments of coordinates of uniform distribution on unit sphere

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability

Suppose $(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)\in\mathbb{C}^n$ are drawn uniformly at random from the unit hypersphere. Since $|\alpha_1|^2 + \cdots + |\alpha_n|^2 = 1$, by symmetry it is clear $\mathbb{E}[|\alpha_i|^2] = 1/n$.

In the Proof of Theorem 1 in this thesis: https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.0378 it is claimed that
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}[|\alpha_i|^2|\alpha_j|^2] = \frac{1+\delta_{i,j}}{n(n+1)}
\end{equation*}
where $\delta_{i,j}$ is the Kroneker delta.

Is this similarly obvious by some symmetry?

Comment: I think the technique in this comment can be used: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4303209/352534, but a simple argument would be great.

Comment: Possibly, but the variables here are *not* independent--only identically distributed. It takes a delicate translation.

Comment: yes, but the $\alpha_i$ in this setting are distributed like $x_i / \sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2}$ where $x_i$ are iid normals, which is the setting considered in the problem.

Comment: It doesn't look like the $\alpha_i$s are distributed around 0... no? I also suspect you want them to be real, not complex... Your constraints appears odd...

Comment: Oh yeah, I misspoke. To get what I have here (for the complex case) from the real case you have to modify the approach in that comment a bit.

Comment: I just come to some similar question. This page (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306806/distribution-and-moments-of-fracx-ix-j-sum-i-1n-x-i2-when-x-is-are/4303209#4303209) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a seat-of-the-pants partial demonstration, but I just know there are elegant proofs in MSE, and I  have no gumption to  translate them.

Take coordinates *x,y,z,...,s* on your $S^{n-1}$, so you have
$$x^2+y^2+z^2+...+s^2=1, \leadsto \\
\langle x^2\rangle =1/n,
$$
by symmetry, as you noted.

Square this starting normalization condition to a hypersphere, and take expectation values,
$$
(x^2+y^2+z^2+...+s^2)^2=1, \leadsto \\
n\langle x^4\rangle +{n(n-1)\over 2} \langle 2 x^2y^2  \rangle =1,
$$
by symmetry of the  quartics and the ${n(n-1)\over 2}$ dissimilar pairs.

***If*** it holds that $$
 \langle  x^4  \rangle =2  \langle  x^2y^2  \rangle \tag{*}
$$
for all *n*, a principle I recall Bargmann (my teacher) aware of, but whose symmetry eludes me at the moment, then these two relations suffice to solve for
$$
\langle  x^2y^2  \rangle =1/n(n+1) ; \qquad \langle  x^4  \rangle =2/n(n+1) .
$$

---

- *Note aded*
  Satisfy yourself how this works for *n=3*, a beach-ball, by use of [Archimedes' theorem](https://www.bogotobogo.com/Algorithms/uniform_distribution_sphere.php).

The point is angular variables are, paradoxically!,  contraindicated, as they require a fancy measure (cf preceding link). Instead, just use the flat variable $\chi\equiv x^2$ in my illustration for the 1-sphere, $S^1$, the circle, *n=2* ,  below.

The measure is flat, $\int_0^1 d\chi =1$, so that
$$ 
\langle x^2\rangle = \langle \chi \rangle =\int_0^1 d\chi  ~ \chi= 1/2, \\
\langle y^2\rangle  =\int_0^1 d\chi  ~ (1-\chi)= 1/2, \\
\langle x^4\rangle  =\int_0^1 d\chi  ~  \chi^2= 1/3, \\
\langle x^2 y^2\rangle  =\int_0^1 d\chi  ~ \chi(1-\chi) = 1/2-1/3=1/6,  
$$
satisfying the condition (*), and illustrating the *n(n+1)* denominator origin.

Comment: Those relations aren't independent.

Comment: I think this is what J.G. was saying, but aren't the equations scalar multiples of one another?

Comment: Oops... Indeed; right you are...  I need another symmetry to make one E twice the other... I know there is an argument that Bargmann had...

Comment: I (lamely) updated the answer to reflect the condition.